# Why addon not showing in the addon list to activate?

Tags: add-on

Here below i have written a small addon to apply all modifiers at 1 click

```
import bpy

# Get the active object
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Apply all modifiers to the object
for modifier in obj.modifiers:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=modifier.name)
```

The script is running perfectly. But when trying to activate it does not show in the list. I have save with the `name.py`.

Any suggestion or help why the script not showing in the list to activate.

Comment: That is not an addon, that is a script What would you expect would happen if you were to activate it in the addons list?

Comment: There's already a built-in addon for that. Under Edit > Preferences > Addons, search for and enable Interface: Modifier Tools. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/addons/interface/modifier_tools.html#modifier-tools

Comment: I wouldn't need an add-on for that actually... isn't Ctrl+A > _Apply All Modifiers_ not comfortable enough? It even works with multiple objects selected in the viewport.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Doesn't that option need the Modifier Tools addon to be enabled? - Not sure if that's enabled by default in new installations nowadays.

Comment: @JohnEason You're probably right... still I wouldn't need an extra add-on to enable for a single function if there comes one with Blender that does this and more ;) But even if you don't enable the _Modifier Tools_, instead you could use Ctrl+A > _Visual Geometry to Mesh_, it does basically the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted isn't an addon, it is just a script.

The simplest possible addon looks like this:

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Test Add-on",
    "blender": (3, 4, 0),
    "category": "Object",
}
def register():
    print("Hello World")
def unregister():
    print("Goodbye World")
```

> `bl_info`
>
> is a dictionary containing add-on metadata such as the title, version and author to be displayed in the Preferences add-on list. It also specifies the minimum Blender version required to run the script; older versions won’t display the add-on in the list.
>
> `register`
>
> is a function which only runs when enabling the add-on, this means the module can be loaded without activating the add-on.
>
> `unregister`
>
> is a function to unload anything setup by `register`, this is called when the add-on is disabled
> Source: [Add-on Tutorial - What is an Add-on? — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html#what-is-an-add-on)

It does nothing, not even importing Blender's python module, but it would show up in the addons list once installed:

[image: demo minimal addon]

You could also look up the addon template in the text editor's templates menu:

[image: addon template]

In general, I invite you to have a look at : [Add-on Tutorial — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html#)